# How to make a query that filter out two AND conditions on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

**Write a query that returns all pages that have been visited by at least one child (demo='child') and ALSO has been visited by at least one person aged 18-25 (demo='18-25').  Your query should return a set of urls.**

I am not sure how to write a query that filters out results based on Two AND statements on the same column and it returns out an empty set.

These are the two tables:

**User**

| uid | ip | demo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 001 | child |
| B | 002 | 18-25 |

**Visit**

| url | dt | uid | src | rev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 1890-05-14 | A | A02 | 10 |
| A01 | 002 | B | A03 | 15 |

```
Select distinct V.url
from Visit V, [User] Z, [User] F
WHERE V.uid = Z.uid AND V.uid = F.uid
AND Z.demo = 'child' AND F.demo = '18-25'
```

This above code returns me an empty set.

**I want it to return A01 as the url**

Comment: It returns an empty set because you cannot have a single row that meets both conditions in your `WHERE` clause. There is no single row where both `z.demo = 'child' AND 'F.demo = '18-25'.`

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL. But MySQL knows no square brackets for quoting identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to use User table twice in the select expression.

I think it can be solved by using nested queries or as called subquery.

In explanation: first you will query the items match the first condition (demo='child') then you will search on the results for the items that also match the second condition (demo='18-25').

Your code will be like this:

```
Select distinct V.url
from Visit V, [User] Z
WHERE V.uid = Z.uid AND Z.demo = 'child'
AND V.url IN (Select distinct V1.url
from Visit V1, [User] Z1
WHERE V1.uid = Z1.uid AND Z1.demo = '18-25')
```

Comment: I forgot to notify about why it returned an empty list. This because there is no any record which can have two values of uid in the same time, and you wrote the condition with AND between the conditions. Then no records matched your query conditions and empty list returned.

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL. MySQL knows no square brackets for quoting identifiers. And explicit `JOIN` syntax should be preferred as it's easier to read and write (without errors).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to join the users, `GROUP BY` the URL, sum the occurrences of children and 18 to 25 year olds and check that these sums each exceed `0` in a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT v.url
       FROM Visit v
            INNER JOIN User u
                       ON v.uid = u.uid
       GROUP BY v.url
       HAVING sum(CASE
                    WHEN u.demo = 'child' THEN
                      1
                    ELSE
                      0
                  END) > 0
              AND sum(CASE
                        WHEN u.demo = '18-25' THEN
                          1
                        ELSE
                          0
                      END) > 0;
```

(Note: In MySQL you don't need the `CASE` expressions but could directly use the Boolean `=` expressions. But a `CASE` doesn't harm there either and with a `CASE` it'll also work in other DBMS. And since it's not entirely clear which DBMS you use a `CASE` expression is a safer bet.)

Another approach is to use a conjunction of `EXISTS`' and correlated subqueries that join the users to the visits and picks the record with the URL and `demo` in question. It would help if you already had a table with only the URLs. I'll simulate that with a derived table aliased `x`.

```
SELECT x.url
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    v.url
                    FROM Visit v) x
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM Visit v
                                      INNER JOIN User u
                                                 ON u.uid = v.uid
                                 WHERE v.url = x.url
                                       AND u.demo = 'child')
                  AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM Visit v
                                          INNER JOIN User u
                                                     ON u.uid = v.uid
                                     WHERE v.url = x.url
                                           AND u.demo = '18-25');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can JOIN on the `User` table twice: once to find a user that is "18-25", and another to find a user that is a "child". If you find both of those (as determined by the `WHERE` clause) then the `Visit` record will be included in the results:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT V.url
  FROM
    Visit V
  LEFT JOIN User U ON (V.uid = U.uid AND U.demo = '18-25')
  LEFT JOIN User U2 on (V.uid = U2.uid AND U2.demo = 'child')
  WHERE
    U.uid IS NOT NULL AND U2.uid IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That returns an empty set as the same user is joined twice and they cannot be a child *and* 18 to 25 year old at the same time. And `DISTINCT` is not a function. The parenthesis aren't needed and may mislead.

Comment: @stickybit The same user is *not* joined twice: table `U` is joined as the user where `demo='18-25'` and table `U2` is joined as the user where `demo='child'`. In other words, "visited by at least one child (demo='child') and ALSO has been visited by at least one person aged 18-25 (demo='18-25')" as OP requested. Regarding `DISTINCT` not being a function, agreed; I've edited my question to remove the parens.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. You try to join a user twice but since one row from `visit` only can refer to one row in `user` and since one user cannot be a child and 18 to 25 years old at once (at least) one of the `ON` clauses evaluate to false and the corresponding left join only adds  `NULL`s to the result so the `WHERE` clause never matches any rows.

Comment: @stickybit OP has no requirement that the users be the same. It just stated that one user must be '18-25' and another must be 'child'. And of course both users' `uid` must match `V.uid` So as long as there exists at least one user whose `uid` matches `V.uid` and is '18-25' and at least one user (who will also be a different user) whose `uid` matches `V.uid` and is 'child', then, `V.url` will be included in the result set.

Comment: I don't know how I can explain it any better to you, so that you will understand... So just test your query and you'll see it simply does not work -- it'll always returns an empty set! Then think it through for yourself and you'll see what I mean. You can paste your query into @FanoFN's fiddle I guess.

Comment: @stickybit It's returning an empty set because the data does not include a user who is '18-25' and another user who is 'child'. I think the confusion is that I'm assuming you can add another user record with the same `uid` since the schema didn't preclude that (see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=528e651cf47be351d572c352e5fd0d98)), and you're assuming that isn't possible/allowed.

Comment: Well, it returns an empty set with the OP's sample data but the OP is expecting a non empty set with it. So it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to join `User` table twice and please use the more recommended `JOIN` operator over `comma-join`.

A comment from @stickybit made me realize that I misunderstand the question. Therefore I'll update my answer to something workable for the question requirement. I'll retain most of my original answer with little modifications just to make sure that it can return the desired result for the current set of OP data. Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT url,
       GROUP_CONCAT(demo) dd
  FROM Visit V 
   JOIN User U
    ON V.uid = U.uid
GROUP BY url) A
WHERE dd LIKE '%child%18-25%' OR dd LIKE '%18-25%child%';
```

I know this is not the best solution but I've seen others have posted their version of query based on the same understanding. So, this is just another variant.

Check the [updated demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3803bccb0e7fc9194c2e07b34385a634)

Comment: That'll also find URLs **only** visited by children or **only** visited by 18 to 25 year olds.

Comment: Umm.. I don't understand @stickybit. What am I missing here?

Comment: `INSERT` just a record `('A02', '1890-05-14', 'B', 'A03', 15)` into `Visit` and `'A02'` will be in the result of your queries though `'A20'` hasn't ever been visited by a `'child'`.

Comment: I see, I'll update my answer to something workable. Thanks for the tip @stickybit!